# Value of id in hyperlinks

Tags: php

When creating hyperlinks using the `<a>` tag and an `href` attribute with the value `"g.php?id=hhjjj"`, can we retrieve the value of `id` on the next page using PHP's `$_GET` variable?

Comment: Yes, as stated above with the $_GET superglobal. It's also important to consider the fact that the user can also change this value at will, so input should be validated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In PHP, `$_GET["id"]` will give you the value of `id` as a string (`"hhjjj"`).